# Displays message when are Tab closed By State Status in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, use-state

When I do a specific process and   I want the user to not accidentally close the tab or reload the page

I need to alert him when he closes the tab just as the process continues

Once the process is complete I would like to cancel the message

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching I found the code that does it

```
const [state, setState] = React.useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    const cb = e => {
      if (state) {
        console.log({ s: state });
        e.preventDefault();
        e.returnValue = "Are you sure?";
      }
    };
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", cb);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", cb);
  }, [state]);
```

I am attaching an example

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-kepler-lcnb5?file=/src/App.tsx)